# Listbox posted Form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox, forms, http-post

im trying to post all the options' value in a select element(listBox) back to server to a MVC project

```
<select mulitple name="listboxA">
  <option value="one">text one</option>
  <option value="two">text one</option>
  <option value="three">text one</option>
</select>
```

However, on srever side, the value in `Request.Form("listboxA")` is `"one,two,three,"`, there is an extra comma at the end, which result in an extra unwanted empty string in the parameter (type of `List<string>`).

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Request.Form["listboxA"].TrimEnd(',')` on your controller.

Comment: i know i can do that, just want to know how is this happening and if there is a better way than just trim the string